# What would having both a package and its subpackages in PYTHONPATH break?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

We have a package that is structured like:

```
ParentDirectory/
  Able/
    __init__.py
    Baker/
      __init__.py
      stuff.py
      Charlie/
        __init__.py
        things.py
```

and with ParentDirectory in PYTHONPATH, Charlie imports in the ordinary fashion:
`from Able.Baker import Charlie`

One of my colleagues wants to make PYTHONPATH include "`ParentDirectory;ParentDirectory/Able;ParentDirectory/Able/Baker`" so that they can import Baker and Charlie directly as if they were top level:

```
import Able
import Baker
import Charlie
```

**Will this break anything**?

(it seems like bad practice to me, but I can't articulate a specific reason why it is bad.)

Comment: (we need to have this external directory available from multiple Anaconda environments which is why PYTHONPATH and not .pth files)

Comment: If you want to be able to import each package separately... maybe they should be separate packages?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm trying to come up with specific examples that I can use to show why the alternative is bad.

Answer (score 3):

It will absolutely break things. If you do this, `Baker` and `Charlie` will be distinct modules from `Able.Baker` and `Able.Baker.Charlie`. Importing both `Baker` and `Able.Baker` will run module initialization twice. You will have two copies of classes (and functions, and most other things, but the effects are worse for classes). You will break relative imports, because `Baker` and `Charlie` will be top-level, not inside a package. It is an all-around terrible idea.